# How could I watch the recorded live streams using wowza engine?

Tags: amazon-ec2, live-streaming, wowza

We wanted to let our clients review the live streams made. We checked the option ‘Record all live streams’ from the Wowza Engine Manager. We know that the streamings are being saved inside the wowza content folder but since our engine is located in a EC2 instance we could find no easy way for our clients to watch them but to download them through console.

Can the manager be configured to show the videos there like it is on Wowza Streaming Cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an option for you, you can move your recordings to s3.  You should first mount an s3 bucket in your filesystem ([s3fs](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?72-How-to-use-the-FUSE-based-file-system-backed-by-Amazon-S3)), then configure the module [ModuleMediaWriterFileMover](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?246-How-to-move-recordings-from-live-streams) to move the recorded files to the mount dir.

Comment: Thanks. I read about that possibility but I was hoping there was an easier way. I sent email to wowza and they replied there was no way yet (they will do it eventually)  to see a list of video files available from your application's content folder in the Wowza Manager UI.

The only way via the Manager is to type in the stream file name in the VOD application test player.

Comment: You could try to setup a simple web server (e.g. Nginx) and make it listen on a port not used by WOWZA, then serve the static videos from the content folder.

Answer (score 1):

in my case I set up a webserver(apache2)  on the same machine listening on port 8080 (wowza uses 80 for hls streaming), then I set a symbolic link from /var/www/html/content to {Wowza installation Folder} /content this way the users can reach the recordings at http://youserver.com:8080/content

by default apache will list all files on the folder and if the file is .mp4 the browser will play the video,  if file is .flv it will be downloaded

Answer (score 0):

A better approach:
Move the files to an S3 bucket as soon as they are ready.

Wowza actually has a module for this (of course it does, everybody needs it)

https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?813-How-to-upload-recorded-media-to-an-Amazon-S3-bucket-(ModuleS3Upload)

So, as you do with every other module,

1- include files in lib folder

2- go to the engine manager UI and add the module

3- set your keys and bucket in the manager properties

Restart and done. Works like a charm and no files are uploaded before they are ready.

Note: Be careful because unless you are naming each stream with a timestamp like I'm doing, amazon will overwrite the file when uploading one with the same name.